# How can I toggle fire using redstone in SSP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The Yogscast uses redstone-toggled fire, probably using [this mod](http://craftbook.sk89q.com/wiki/Redstone_netherrack). However, CraftBook is only available for SMP. How can I get this feature into SSP?

Comment: And just an FYI, its not really possible to get an SMP mod into SSP unless its also compatible in SSP.. Works this way in both directions unfortunately.

Comment: Right. I wasn't looking to get this exact mod, I was looking to get something that adds this feature from the mod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 1.2, you can ignite blocks using a fire charge launched by dispensers,
but you will waste a lot of materials.

Comment: Well, sure, a fire charge could be used eventually to _start_ a fire, but there'd be no good way to toggle that fire _off_ using redstone (unless you want to get creative with pistons and water and whatnot)

Comment: you can turn it off by using flood gate.

Comment: which falls under the category of "getting creative with pistons"

Answer (score 3):

You want this mod: [**Redstone Activated Netherrack**](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/849677-100sspsmpredstone-activated-netherrackbasemodloadermodloadermp/), or as you pointed out, [**Redstoned Netherrack**](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/904931-110ssp-daniel-grays-mods-650-downloads/#sixth)

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll check it out, and accept if (probably when) it works

Comment: Sadly, it's a 1.0.0 mod... *le sigh *begins a quest for similar mods* Here we go! [I found one](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/904931-110ssp-daniel-grays-mods-650-downloads/#sixth) So... should I post that as an answer now, then?

Comment: Never mind, that mod works such that now I can't place blocks on top of netherrack. Good thing I made a backup.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use flint and steels in a dispenser, if you don't want to use fire charges